# Template class not found when calling from static template function

Tags: c++, templates, g++

file securityController.h (shortened)

```
#ifndef SECURITYCONTROLLER_H_
#define SECURITYCONTROLLER_H_

#include "hallSensor.h"
#include "project.h"

template<Axis axis>
class SecurityController{
public:
static void saturate(double& value){
    HallSensor<X>::isAtEnd();   // DOES NOT WORK, nor do the other calls
}
};
#endif /* SECURITYCONTROLLER_H_ */
```

file hallSensor.h (shortened)

```
#ifndef HALLSENSOR_H_
#define HALLSENSOR_H_
#include "project.h"
#include "control.h"

template<Axis axis>
class HallSensor{

private:
static volatile bool triggered[2];
static volatile bool state[2]; //the real current state
static volatile int triggeredPosition[2];

public:
static bool isAtEnd(){
    return triggered[1];
}
};

template<Axis axis> volatile bool HallSensor<axis>::triggered[2];
template<Axis axis> volatile bool HallSensor<axis>::state[2];
template<Axis axis> volatile int HallSensor<axis>::triggeredPosition[2];

template<> bool HallSensor<ALL>::init();

#endif /* HALLSENSOR_H_ */
```

This works: (main.cpp)

```
#include "hallSensor.h"
int main(){
HallSensor<X>::isAtEnd(); } //WORKS
```

The calls inside securityController.h do not work. Gcc/c++ outputs the following:

```
securityController.h: In static member function 'static void    SecurityController<axis>::saturate(double&)':
securityController.h:19:3: error: 'HallSensor' was not declared in this scope
HallSensor<X>::isAtEnd();
^
securityController.h:19:16: error: '::isAtEnd' has not been declared
HallSensor<X>::isAtEnd();   //and so on
```

Axis is a simple enum with values for X,Y,Z,All

Why can I call the static template function from a regular function, but not from inside a static template function?

Comment: Neither the call with X, nor the calls with axis do work

Comment: Could you reduce the code to the problem?

Comment: Use Axis instead of axis?

Comment: I shortened the code.. The shortened code still does not compile

Comment: Explain how the line `HallSensor<X>::isAtEnd();` is supposed to work if the template argument is called `Axis`.

Comment: @HonkyTonk: you have missed *Axis is a simple enum with values for X,Y,Z,All*

Comment: @Jarod42 No, but calling a function in `HallSensor<X>` requires instantiation and I got a bit curious as to how this was supposed to work. It very much looks like the OP either has misunderstood template mechanics or I'm just too stupid to see the use of the construction.

Comment: By providing a definition for init() in HallSensor, it compiles for me with g++/gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)

Comment: @HonkyTonk, what do you mean by instantiation? The method is static so I assumed I could use the class without creating an instance?

Comment: For the compiler to be able to generate object code, it has to generate code for the template where you're using X as parameter. This includes making it possible to resolve *calls* to template classes. So, your call, in the static method, will *force* the compiler to instantiate `HallSensor<X>`. Class instance is not the same as template instance.

Comment: Alright, but that should be fine, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I get it to compile, if I forward declare the HallSensor class in the SecurityController.

e.g.

```
 template <Axis axis> class HallSensor;
```

I have no Idea why that is necessary, since I am including "hallSensor.h" directly..